# Creating Dynamic nested HTML tags using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class like this

```
var htmlElements=function(){
    var __this=this;
    this.type=''; 
    this.parentDiv='';
    this.id='';
    this.draw=function(){
        if(__this.type=='div'){
            $('<div/>', {
                'id': __this.id,
            })
            .appendTo(__this.parentDiv);
        }
    }
}
```

From my consumer class I create the object of this class fill properties and call the draw method. Like this. In dom i have a `div` with id `staticDiv` I didn't create it dynamically

```
var htmlElementsobj=htmlElements();
htmlElements.type='div';
htmlElements.id='firstDiv';
htmlElements.parentDiv='#staticDiv'
htmlElements.draw();
```

To this point it works fine but when I try to draw another element inside a dynamic created `div` like this

```
var htmlElementsobj=htmlElements();
    htmlElements.type='div';
    htmlElements.id='nestedDiv';
    htmlElements.parentDiv='#firstDiv'
    htmlElements.draw();
```

It didnt draw. But If I change its parent property to `staticDiv` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to `htmlElements` as an object, when I think you mean to refer to `htmlElementsobj`. Also, you want to call `new htmlElements()` to create objects:

```js
var htmlElements=function(){
  var __this = this;
  this.type = ''; 
  this.parentDiv = '';
  this.id = '';
  this.draw = function(){
    if(__this.type=='div'){
      $('<div/>', {
         'id': __this.id,
      }).text(__this.id).    // for debugging / visualization
         appendTo(__this.parentDiv);
    }
  };
};

var htmlElementsobj = new htmlElements();
    htmlElementsobj.type = 'div';
    htmlElementsobj.id = 'firstDiv';
    htmlElementsobj.parentDiv = '#staticDiv'
    htmlElementsobj.draw();

htmlElementsobj = new htmlElements();
    htmlElementsobj.type = 'div';
    htmlElementsobj.id = 'nestedDiv';
    htmlElementsobj.parentDiv = '#firstDiv'
    htmlElementsobj.draw();
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="staticDiv"></div>
```